# Colocar valor por defecto a campo html tipo FILE

Tags: php, html5

Luego de sacar la informacion de una base de datos, para que el usuario la edite, quiero colocar un valor predeterminado en el campo FILE donde va una imagen, para no tener q volver a buscar la imagen si el usuario no quiere cambiar ese aspecto. Si no se preselecciona la opcion original o el usuario la busca manualmente entonces el campo FILE quedara nulo luego de la edicion y se perdera la imagen que anteriormente estaba guardada.

```
IMAGEN: <input type="file" name='img' value='<?php echo $img; ?>'>
```

Asi fue como lo intente, pero por no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que quede asi, relleno como el resto de los campos del form.

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué quieres hacer esto? Habitualmente los inputs de tipo `file` no tienen un archivo por defecto, entre otras cosas por cuestiones de seguridad.

Comment: No es posible almacenar un valor en un input type file por razones de seguridad. Más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html).

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, ya lo resolvi por otras vias de todas formas :)

Answer (score 0):

Si es para un formulario de edición, lo que se suele hacer es mostrar en una etiqueta `<img>` la ruta de la imagen que está precargada en la BD y si el usuario la quiere cambiar, se le da la opción con el campo de tipo `file`.

**Nota:** *Evita almacenar imágenes directamente en las tablas de la BD. En su lugar, almacena la imagen en un directorio y la ruta al directorio en el campo de la BD.*

```
//$img contendrá la ruta a la imagen
IMAGEN: <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">
CAMBIAR IMAGEN: <input type="file" name='img'>
```

Luego, si el campo llega seteado, cargas la nueva imagen en el directorio y actualizas la ruta en la BD. Por ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
  $ubicacionFinal = 'images/' . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $ubicacionFinal)) {
    //Ejecutar la sentencia SQL para actualizar la ruta en la BD
    ... UPDATE tabla SET campo = $ubicacionFinal WHERE ...
    echo "Se reemplazó la imagen correctamente.";
  } else {
    echo "Error al cargar la imagen.";
  }
}
```

Esto solo es una idea, debes asegurarte de hacer las validaciones pertinentes previamente y usar sentencias preparadas. Adapta el ejemplo a tu proyecto.